# Angular and JS do not agree on what are equal objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am creating an application to display some data. It has a grid and a data source.

I will show you the problem first and try to explain the situation.

```
$scope.onSelectRow = function (row, rowId) { 
                var a = row;
                var b = _.findWhere($scope.gridData.rows, {id: rowId});
                var c = a === b;
                console.log('Does JS think they are the same ? -> ' + c);
                console.log('Does Angular think they are the same ? -> ' + angular.equals(a, b));
                console.log('\nThe objects:');
                console.log(a);
                console.log(b);
                console.log('\nThe indexes:'); // what i really need
                console.log('Index of a:' + $scope.gridData.rows.indexOf(row));
                console.log('Index of b:' + $scope.gridData.rows.indexOf(b));
{
```

In this piece of code I am trying to find out the index of the element. The element was initially in the $scope.gridData.rows array. This array is displayed on a grid on the screen. The onSelectRow function is fired when i select a row and is passed 2 arguments

- row -> the whole row of the table which is directly mapped to the $scope.gridData.rows array
- rowId -> the Id property of the row element (the same row element as the 'row' argument a.k.a rowId = row.id )

The output of those lines of code one time is 
http://s23.postimg.org/apl2ebatn/Stack_Overflow_Normal_Pic.png

But when the data is updated and reloaded and then someone clicks on a row again and the same logic is ran the output is
http://s12.postimg.org/6s4d6rajh/Stack_Overflow_Strange_Pic.png

In the first time angular and JS agree that the objects are equal, however on the second picture JS does not think that the objects are equal but angular does ... and in principle they are equal as you can see since i have printed them but mainly because they come from the same source.

In the end all i care about is the index of the selected element in the array of elements however i was trying to avoid searching in the array to find the object and then find its index since i should already have the correct object returned to me by the table.

Any ideas ?

Comment: here's what equals does: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals

Comment: Is the grid `ng-repeat` based ? In that case, just pass `$index` to the function, it contains the index of the element inside the source array.

Comment: @Alex - good suggestion however i can't use that in my case.

Answer (score 1):

In the end after reading through the documentation more carefully and keeping in mind @borja's answer it turns out that `angular.equals` does a '===' comparison but also checks some other things and than comes up with an answer.

From https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals

> Two objects or values are considered equivalent if at **least one of the
>   following is true**:
>
> - Both objects or values pass === comparison.
> - Both objects or values are of the same type and all of their properties are > equal by comparing
>     them with angular.equals.
> - Both values are NaN. (In JavaScript, NaN ==
>     NaN => false. But we consider two NaN as equal)
> - Both values represent
>     the same regular expression (In JavaScript, /abc/ == /abc/ => false.
>     But we consider two regular expressions as equal when their textual
>     representation matches).

Answer (score 0):

First of all the easiest way to find the index is to pass it from the view using $index in the ng-repeat.
Your problem is that the a and b are not the same reference.
The objects have the same type and the same properties and values so angular says they are [equal](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals). But because the reference of a and b are different === returns they are not equal

Comment: Yeah that's what i though also but wanted to be sure.